# Can images be preloaded without the cache using Image objects?

Tags: javascript, image, caching

I am trying to figure out a way to (nearly) guarantee that image files located on a server will be available for appending to the DOM with no delay after an initial loading period.

I've been using a standard preloading technique like:

```
var images_to_load = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];
for(var i=0; i<images_to_load.length; i++){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = images_to_load[i];
}
```

But I've learned that whether this works depends on factors like server and browser settings, as well as the number of images to load.

I'm wondering if storing the images in memory, and then appending the Image object directly to the DOM will change how the preloading behaves. Does this bypass the cache? For example:

```
var images_to_load = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];
var images = [];
for(var i=0; i<images_to_load.length; i++){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = images_to_load[i];
  images.push(img);
}

document.getElementById('target').appendChild(images[0]);
```

(Relatedly: What tools are available for testing this kind of behavior?)

Comment: I think you need more clarification. Where are the original pictures? this array contains just names. Are these files on the client machine ? or they are on the servers and you load it from client side ? What is the serverside platform if you have any ?

Comment: I've clarified that the image files are on the server and need to be loaded by the client.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarantee they are each loaded is to use a load event handler

```
for(var i=0; i<images_to_load.length; i++){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = images_to_load[i];
  images.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('target').appendChild(img);
  };
}
```

Note this will append in order loaded, not array order.

As for cache , any cached images will load much quicker, that's all

Comment: Will images loaded like this remain loaded for the duration of the session? In other words, if I have a single-page app that users view for 25 minutes, and I load all images that they will see using this method at the start of the session, will the browser clear the memory at some point? I need the image presented 20 minutes into the session to display just as quickly as the image loaded at the start.

Comment: shouldn't be a problem